# MSChart C# Error Bar Graph With Dynamic Upper and Lower Bounds

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I am working with MSChart in C#.  I am given simulation data for the manufacturing time of three different products. I need to create a graph that LOOKS like an error bar graph that contains three points, but what each point really contains is the average time value, and the upper and lower bounds of the error bar at each point are the maximum and minimum time values of the simulation.  The problem I have found is that with MSChart, the error range is static; it is the same for every point on the graph.  I need an error bar graph with a different minimum and maximum for every point.  I have an image of what the graph should look like, but of course, I am not allowed to post images.

I thought I could create a workaround, however inconvenient, by creating 6 series in the graph, 2 for each point, then add the maximum to one and the minimum to the other, and hide the respective lower and upper bound.  Trying this, however, makes the graph a big red X.  I am wondering if this capability is not possible with the .Net MSChart.  Will I have to look at third party libraries for this?

Answer (score 2):

The following uses the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting libraries which I think have been part of .Net since 4.0.

```
Chart aChart = new Chart();
ChartArea aChartArea = new ChartArea();
aChart.ChartAreas.Add(aChartArea);
aChart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100,100);

Series aSeries = mChart.Series.Add("SomeSeriesName");
aSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.ErrorBar;
aSeries.Points.AddXY(firstXPoint, firstMiddleYPoint, firstLowerYBound, firstUpperYBound);
aSeries.Points.AddXT(secondXPoint, secondMiddleYPoint, secondLowerYBound, secondUpperYBound);
aChart.SaveImage("outputPath/outputName.jpg", ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks! Quick note, do not set the `ErrorBarSeries` or the `ErrorBarType` with this method, or it won't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434344/error-bar-change-upper-lower-and-center-errors-independently-of-each-other/20436321#20436321